# How can I conveniently close all read-only buffers?

Tags: command-line, buffers

For a longer running vim session, the number of buffers increases. However, often `$VIMRUNTIME` files, system files and netrw buffers can usually be closed with “closed” eyes. These are typically read-only. Currently, I close once in a while vim and reopen the interesting files via `CtrlPMRU` (configured to ignore many files as those just mentioned). This seems to be a suboptimal workflow.

I have found following question with a good answer on stackoverflow on how to close multiple buffers in a single step:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3155461/how-to-delete-multiple-buffers-in-vim

However, you have to come up with a globbing expression to select the ones you wish to close. In my case I want to close all read-only buffers which cannot be adressed this way.

Does anyone know how to close read-only buffers conveniently?

Answer (score 6):

This command should output the number of the last buffer in the buffer list (see `:h bufnr()`):

```
:echo bufnr('$')
```

---

This command should output the range of buffer numbers, from the first one to the last one (see `:h range()`):

```
:echo range(1, bufnr('$'))
```

---

This command should output the `'readonly'` option of the buffer `123` (see `:h getbufvar()`):

```
:echo getbufvar(123, '&l:ro')
```

---

This command should remove from the list of buffer numbers `[1,2,3,4,5]`, the ones whose `'readonly'` option is unset (see `:h filter()`):

```
:echo filter([1,2,3,4,5], {i,v -> getbufvar(v, '&l:ro') == 1})
```

---

This command should output the whole range of buffer numbers, whose `'readonly'` option is set:

```
:echo filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), {i,v -> getbufvar(v, '&l:ro') == 1})
```

---

You could join the numbers of the last command, and pass them to `:bd` (see `:h :exe` and `:h join()`):

```
:exe 'bd '.join(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), {i,v -> getbufvar(v, '&l:ro') == 1}))
```

And to make this simpler to execute, you could install a custom `:BdReadOnly` command (see `:h :com`):

```
com! -bar  BdReadOnly  exe 'bd '.join(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), {i,v -> getbufvar(v, '&l:ro') == 1}))
```

---

There may be “holes” in the range. That is, some index may have been used in the past for a buffer, but the latter may have been deleted since then. In this case, the index is not re-used for another buffer.
For such non-existing buffer, `getbufvar()` should then return an empty string:

```
:echo getbufvar(999999999, '&l:ro') is# ''
    → 1
```

So, the previous test in the lambda expression should fail:

```
getbufvar(v, '&l:ro') == 1
```

And, I think, the index should be correctly filtered.

Also, if the buffers which are deleted are not exactly the ones you want, you may need to tweak the condition `getbufvar(v, '&l:ro') == 1` in the lambda expression, and build a more complex one.
In this case, you could be interested in some other functions (see `:h buffer-functions`).

To name a few:

- `bufexists(123)` will tell you whether the buffer `123` exists
- `buflisted(123)` will tell you whether the buffer `123` is currently listed
- `bufname(123)` will give you the name of the buffer `123`, and `empty(bufname(123))` will test whether it has one in the first place
- `win_findbuf(123)` will tell you in which window(s) the buffer `123` is being displayed, and `empty(win_findbuf(123))` will tell you whether it is displayed anywhere in the first place

Comment: Note that the arrow lambda style is vim8 only, I believe.